# Silverlight 5 - PivotViewer Details Pane Disappears on a touch screen

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer

We've got a fairly basic implementation of the PivotViewer that we've put on a HP touch screen PC.  Everything works as expected - and on the left hand pane you can select options, clear options etc.

The problem is when you select a card, the right hand pane is displayed as expected, but if you choose an item from this right hand pane (although this action works and the screen animates to show the new results) the next time you select an item the right hand pane is blank.

You get this behaviour even when you use the mouse on the touch screen.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

This same implementation works fine on every other PC - just not the touch screen where it is to be deployed!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although other samples I downloaded gave the same behaviour on the touch screen I found that a sample showing a custom details pane sorted things out.

I downloaded the sample from here:

http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2011/10/sl5-pivotviewer-custom-detailpanestyle/

It worked much better on the touch screen anyway as I made big buttons on my custom pane, rather than the hyperlinks that were there before.